# C# WPF Control Library No accessible constructors

Tags: c#, wpf, control-library

I have been working on creating a control resource library for a reusable dialog message box and have run into some issues. Below I have just the bar bones code behind and ViewModel

```cs
namespace MyLibrary
{
    public partial class WindowsMessage : UserControl
    {
        public WindowsMessage(Window parentWindow)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Code behind stuff
        }
    }

    public class WindowsMessageViewModel : DialogBaseWindowViewModel
    {
        // ViewModel stuff
    }
}
```

I also have a `ResourceDictionary` that must be referenced by the using application that has the following:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyLibrary">

    <!-- Sets Datatype for control used as content in DialogBaseWindow. -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:WindowsMessageViewModel}">
        <local:WindowsMessage/>
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

This all works when the code is part of an application, but I get an error message that states:

"The type "WindowsMessage" does not include any accessible constructors."

Is there a way to get this working for Control Libraries?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with libraries. Anything you create in XAML as an XML element has to have a parameterless constructor. Add a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Ahhhh...I did add a parameter when I converted it to the library. It was something needed to work in the way I wanted it to work. Guess I need to figure that out now. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How were you planning to set the parent window for the instance created in the DataTemplate? Personally I'd write a method using `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent()` to walk the parent chain until you hit a `Window` (or relativesource ancestortype=window, derp), and call that in the constructor to have the control find its own parent window automatically.

Comment: Create a bindable DependencyProperty for the window parameter (or let some code-behind in your UserControl figure out its parent window whenever an instance of your UserControl is being added/removed from the logical tree, assuming there is a related method or event allowing you to do that)...

Comment: Well, I wanted to be able to plug in a window parameter so when using this I can choose the window a specific dialog window pops up on. I wanted to choose the parent and not have one auto chosen for me.

Comment: Well, ignoring your `WindowsMessage` code and addressing your use case: How would you even specify the desired window there in the DataTemplate? Say like `<local:WindowsMessage ParentWindow=" ??? " />`

Comment: @DavidBentley Ah, I see. Can you go into more detail about who's responsible for showing these dialogs, and how that works?

Comment: I have a window with this: `<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Content="{Binding}"></ContentPresenter>`. I then assign the data context for that window and plug in the user control. The user control constructor is not even really used.

Comment: Yes, I made an edit on my answer as it does contain an `InitializeComponent();` call.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to explain, you don't. Good luck.

Comment: https://github.com/pvpxan/MVVMTemplate is where you can find an older version of my code. Quite a bit is being converted to a library. My specific dialog code uses DialogBaseWindow, WindowsMessage, and DialogService. Probably faster to look that over.

Comment: @EdPlunkett There is quite a bit to explain it might be easier to just look at my code.

Comment: Yeah, so I found a more elegant way of handling a Window parameter. Part of the dialog generation uses a helper class and I added another field to that for Window. Should have done it that way from the beginning.